# Is it a good way to only rely on PayPal Checkout when it comes to Securing a website from unintended use?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am planning a website based on C# and ASP.NET MVC on which I want to offer a small function for a small amount of money. I dont want to use User Profiles because I dont want to do the managing part (like user/pwd) of it and save time. (I know there is a built in User-Handling in ASP.NET but I **dont want a User-Login** here because no one would register an account for this little function)

So a Idea comes to my mind that I could simply offer a PayPal-Button to let the User pay the money and let PayPal handle the redirect with an response key/hash (I think this is how it works) and on the redirected page on my site validate the payment through the key/hash from paypal to call the function the user paid for. Something like a paywall I think.

Is this a safe approach to secure my function and only show it to users who have paid or is this vulnerable to brute-forcing my application with a massive amount of keys to get away with not paying at all?

Comment: How will the user come back to your site later, if you aren't creating a username and password? They save some kind of unique URL and always revisit it? Your ongoing authentication is a bigger problem than how you initially verify a payment was made.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody here can guess for you. You're trying to associate Paypal with brute-forcing _your own implementation_ of their API and whatever security design you come up with for you own app.

Comment: @PrestonPHX - you don't _need_ to have user/pwd on your site just to implement Paypal. "Guest checkout" (no account needed) is ubiquitous in ecommerce.

Comment: You *do* need a user/pwd to secure parts of a website against unintended use. "Guest checkout" (no account needed) does not fit this use case. It's possible the question here was wrongly worded, and no securing of the site is necessary -- what's actually being asked is a way to confirm whether a real payment was made? If so the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: @PrestonPHX In fact I don't want a user/pwd secured area. I only want a site on which the user is redirected by paypal with a payment-id with which I can then validate the successfull payment and show my function. If there isn't a payment-id or the given id is invalid then the function isn't shown and the user will be redirected to the main page. I have clarified the question. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reliable ways to confirm that a PayPal payment has been successful:

1. Synchronously: A server-side, API-based integration
2. Asynchronously: Any integration, and wait for a Webhook or IPN notification from PayPal for confirmation.

I'll cover the first way.

- Integrate PayPal Checkout, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

  [Here is a demo pattern of the client-side UI](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)
- The server side portion of this type of integration (particularly for the transaction set up and capture API calls) is discussed here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

  - [Set up the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/)
  - [Capture the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/)

---

If you do choose to implement a server-side integration, then -- once everything is working for the happy path -- don't neglect to implement funding failure error handling: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/ ;  This will allow buyers to choose a different funding instrument if e.g. their first card is declined by the capture attempt